# Internet Explorer bug! Working only when search button pressed (enter not working)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

This is the search engine script. This script is working on all browsers when I press enter or search button, but I'm facing a problem while using it on Internet Explorer. In IE,  output is not coming with enter click, but output is coming with search button click:

```
function searchForm() {
            
            document.writeln("<form name=\"search\" action=\"index.html\" method=\"get\">");
            document.writeln("<input type=\"text\" name=\"searchTxt\" style=\"border:2px solid #ccc; color:#000;height:26px; width:365px; margin-bottom:0pt;\"/>");

    document.writeln("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Search!\" name=\"search\" onkeypress=\"return runScript(event)\"style=\"width:81px;height:29px;border-width:0px; cursor:pointer; font-size:0px; background-image:url(\'http://i703.photobucket.com/albums/ww34/studentsicon/search.png'); \"/>");
            
            document.writeln("</form>");
        
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Oh my. No need to escape all of those quotes... Just use single quotes either on the outside or on the inside.

Comment: *Why `document.write` in the first place?*

Answer (score 0):

You should just have the element hidden, then show it when `searchForm` is called. There is no need to `document.writeln` it. Just use CSS or opacity or something.

EDIT: There are unbelievably many things wrong with Internet Explorer. You call them "bugs," Microsoft calls them "features," the rest of us call them "*COUGH COUGH* use Chrome/Firefox."

Comment: Opacity is a bad idea, it'll still take up place. Use CSS `display:none;`.